# How can I convert data into "ddmmyyyy hh:mm:ss"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

All that I have is the number 223 (which is the number of days from Jan 01,2012), and the time at which the event occurred at (for example: 09, 55, 56.38 = (hh, mm, ss)).

In Excel I can get a serial number - in the format `10-Aug-12 09:55:56` - with these four numbers.

In Python I've been having some troubles doing the same. Does anyone have any idea about what commands I could be using?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? It will help us determine where your mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) class in Python's `datetime` module lets you create a time difference, in days (or other units), which you can add to/subtract from `datetime` objects to get a new date.

(Note: the `datetime` module contains a `datetime` object. Yup.)

So, you could construct a `datetime` object using 1st Jan 2012 and the hour, minute and second values you've got, and then add a `timedelta` of 223 days to it.

To get that datetime as a string in your desired format, [the `strftime` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) on the datetime object is your friend.

Putting it all on one line:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
serial_number = (datetime(2012, 1, 1, 9, 55, 56) + timedelta(223)).strftime('%d-%h-%y %H:%M:%S')
```